# Bulk insert/update Vespa documents via HTTP POST and PUT method

Tags: yql, vespa

My script will generate a list of document to be inserted into Vespa. Current, I'm using HTTP POST/PUT to insert/update one document per request. This can be slow if I need to insert a lot of documents.

Hence, I'd like to know if there's more efficient method to complete this kind of job. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/vespa-http-client.html for high feed throughput. There is no direct http api for doing bulk http post/put.